# Laravel Backpack Select2 Attribute - To show foreign key attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have 3 tables below with relationship applied accordingly.

- Order Table - (order_id, stock_id) - Need to have stock id, in order to assign available stock to the order.
- Stock Table - (stock_id, product_id, order_id) - have product id in order to know the product name.
- Product Table - (product_id, name)

When I want to create order, I want to show the available stock to assign for my order.

Below code is able to show me the available stock with its product_id, however, how can I link it to show product name in this case? Is there any specific relationship method or attribute I can use to achieve my objective?

```
$this->crud->addField([
  'name' => 'stock_id', 
  'type' => 'select2', 
  'label' => 'Stock', 
  'entity' => 'stock', 
  'attribute' => 'product_id', 
  'model' => 'App\Models\Stock',
  'options' => (function ($query) {
      return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('order_id', null)->get();
  }),
]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1, In your **Stock Model** ('App\Models\Stock')

```
public function getProductNameAttribute()
{
    return Product::find($this->product_id)->name;
}
```

2, In the **Order Controller**

```
'model' => 'App\Models\Stock',
'attribute' => 'product_name'
```